# Is the following sentence a grammatically correct sentence structure?

Tags: grammar

What is the meaning of "Addresses can be created that require a combination of multiple private keys" ?

Does it mean "Addresses can be created. and Adresses require a combination of multiple private keys" ?

Is the sentence a grammatically correct sentence structure? 
So,
does " Subject1 + Verb1 + that + Verb2 + Object" mean " Subject1 + Verb1. and Subject1 + verb2 + Object " ?

Comment: Yes. "That require a combination of multiple private keys" is a relative clause modifying "addresses". We understand that addresses that require a combination of multiple private keys can be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a standard "**that-clause**" construction which can otherwise be re-ordered as:

- Addresses *that require a combination of multiple private keys* can be created.

This means that such addresses can be created.

Comment: does "The cat that  is small is black" mean "The cat is black that is small" ? does "The man that is tall is poor" mean "The man is poor that is tall? So, does " Subject1 + Verb1 + that + Verb2 + Object" mean " Subject1 + that + verb2 + Object + Verb1  " ?